# Any masonry layout library for Dart

Tags: dart

I'm looking for any Dartlang library for doing Masonry-layout. Something that similar to http://masonry.desandro.com/ but for Dart instead of JS.

Does anyone know if such library existed? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of such a library for Dart but this JS library probably works with Dart too, at least when you don't use Polymer elements or Angular components with shadowDOM.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer How can you combine the Masonry JS library with Dart? Do you render the view using Dart and have MasonryJS do the layout afterwards?  I could only think the Dart could generate HTML like <div id="container" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".item" }'>

Comment: You can invoke JavaScript from Dart like other Dart functions. I had a brief look at the Masonry code yesterday. As far as I remember you need to call a function and pass one (or more?) elements to that functions. You can do this from Dart. (https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks! I didn't know that you could call JS from Dart. I'll try that.

Comment: You can also register Dart functions to be called from JS if needed. There are many examples here at StackOverflow, just search for `[dart-js-interop]`